# Need help in understanding confusing Typescript function

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I've come across the following code which is a filter callback function on an array. I'm confused trying to understand what this function is doing and am trying to break it down into smaller bits to understand but I can't seem to get my head around it.

I'm trying to learn TypeScript and know some JS but the syntax is confusing for me.

Could someone please explain how this function would operate on an arrays inputs please? a sort of walk through of the syntax in this exampled would be helpful. Thanks.

```
const check = (Boolean as any) as <T>(
  a: T | false | undefined | null | ''
) => a is T;
```

Comment: It would just return `true` for array inputs, since all arrays are truthy.

Comment: Really weird function :D

Comment: @Aplet123 are you able to break it down please with an example, I don't understand it really and I'm not sure what the <T> followed by parentheses means either?

Comment: never be sure about javascript: `Boolean = (()=> false)`  as typeof Boolean; :D

Answer (score 6):

Ok, this function is kinda... crazy. Let's breakdown this code a bit.

First, take the following idiom as an example:

```
const something = ('' as any) as boolean
// something's type is boolean for Typescript, but its value is actually a string!
```

the `(X as any) as Y` idiom is a hack that allows you to tell typescript that something is actually something else. You're taking full control of the type system, and Typescript won't be able to infer the underlying value - and much less catch it. It can lead to bugs, such as the above example where I tell TS that an empty string is a boolean.

Now, consider the next idiom:

```
const isTruthy: <T>( x: T | false | undefined | null | '' ) => x is T
// not yet implemented
```

This declaration tells typescript that "this is a function that takes any type of parameter, and if it returns true it means the parameter is definitely not falsy". This is done by using **Type guards** through the return type "x is T". This is useful because it'll allow you to take a possible-falsy value and verify that it is, in fact, not falsy:

```
const a: any[] | null | undefined = [];
if(isTruthy(a)) {
  // a is any[]
}
```

One very simple way to implement `isTruthy` is by using the `Boolean` function:

```
type Falsy = null | undefined | false | 0 | ''
function isTruthy<T>(value: T | Falsy): value is T {
  return Boolean(value);
}
```

So, whats the point?

let's take a look at your example once again:

```
const check = (Boolean as any) as <T>(
  a: T | false | undefined | null | ''
) => a is T;
```

1. `Boolean` in this code is a *value*. Specifically, it's the Boolean Function.
2. it is cast to `any` and then cast to `<T>( x: T | false | undefined | null | '' ) => x is T`

So, all this code does is declare an alias for the `Boolean` function and tell TS that it is a type guard where if `check(a)` returns *true*, then `a` is not falsy.

Or you could, you know, just check the value itself:

```
type Falsy = null | undefined | false | 0 | ''
const a: string | Falsy = 'test'
if (a) {
  // a is inferred to be just "string"
}
```

## TL;DR

your "check" function does some clever trickery to reuse the `Boolean` function to do exactly what a simple `if()` can already do.

Just check the truthiness of a value with `if(value)` and move on

## <edit>

I missed an important part of the question:

> Could someone please explain how this function would operate on an arrays inputs please? a sort of walk through of the syntax in this exampled would be helpful. Thanks.

in that case, your `check` function can be used with the `filter` method for some nice type inference:

```
const arr = ['a', false, 123, 0, '', null, undefined];

arr.filter(Boolean).forEach(value => {
  // value is possibly falsy even though the `filter` makes sure it isn't
});

const check = (Boolean as any) as <T>(
  a: T | false | undefined | null | ''
) => a is T;

arr.filter(check).forEach(value => {
  // value is string | number | true
});
```

This is because Typescript can't tell that the Boolean function also works just fine as a guard. So that's the one good use-case for your `check` function, though I'd rename it to `isTruthy`.

Comment: Great answer, but you missed at least [one falsey value....](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20NaN%2C%20standing%20for,especially%20in%20floating%2Dpoint%20arithmetic.)

Comment: unfortunately there's no NaN type on Typescript, it's always a `number`.

Comment: You can't do a literal type with NaN like you can with other numbers? Interesting!

Comment: There is a two year old discussiob on github about NaN type: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28682

Comment: @Badashi I agree with Jared Smith, your answer is great!

Comment: @Badashi Just catching up on this and going over each bit - ```(X as any) as Y```  - why does this have to be laid out like this, can you not just do ```X as Boolean``` directly? why does the 'as any' bit have to be applied?

Comment: casting can only be done when types are compatible. For example, `Boolean` is a class that is not compatible with `Function`, but it IS compatible with `any`; `any` OTOH is compatible with `Function`. So `Boolean as Function` fails, but `(Boolean as any) as Function` works.

Comment: @Badashi oh that's interesting, so in the first bit you're casting one type e.g. ```Boolean``` as a type ```any``` and then you're casting it again to type ```Function``` ? So that means the input you are expecting will be a boolean but you want to cast it as a function in the end? this is confusing because in your example you used an empty string as a value and here a Boolean type, I'm trying to follow. Are you able to break that bit down a bit more or do you have a link to something? Thanks for explaining!

Comment: Thanks, I went through the rest of your explanation, I was a bit lost by Type Guards as well and some of the other syntax like <T>, also the Boolean function you mentioned being recast. I will have to try to read again and understand. The function is being used on an array as you described.

Comment: remember that `Boolean` can both be a type(since it is a class) but it is also a function! When you use `X as any`, X must be a value(and functions are values); but `X as any as Y` will tell TS that the **value** X has a **type** Y. Also, remember that `Boolean` is a class while `boolean`(lowercase) is a type, and while `Boolean` as a class or function exists in JS, the `boolean` type doesn't, since types don't exist in JS. It's definitely confusing.

Comment: @Badashi Ok I follow a bit more now after reading your answer a few times. If something is a class does that mean it is also a type then as you explained with the Boolean example above? Can you just clarify how the <T> bit fits into this function please? Great explanations so far, it has helped.

Comment: Also why did you implement isTruthy with the Boolean function, surely if value is T then it doesn't need to run the Boolean function as it's already truthy right?

Comment: 2 final questions that I couldn't add in the comment above in time, where does the value for T come from? In the array example why did you say value is falsy even though filter should make sure that it isn't?